# html video player not able to play small videos from gridfs stream but able to play large videos

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, html5-video, gridfs, range-header

I am able to play large videos like 1GB , and 500MB but for video sizes like 60MB or lesser, the browser is not loading them if it receives content.
[for small videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi07C.png)
[not able to load even metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwS5v.png)

for large video-
[loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBi8U.png)

video html-

```
<video src="${url}" style="width:100% !important; height: inherit; background: black;" controls autoplay muted preload="metadata"></video>
```

I tried manipulating the responses content range , status but none are working.

My server code for response to range request-

```
route.get('/video/:id', async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;`your text`
const range = req.headers.range;`your text`
    console.log(range);
    if (!range || range === undefined) {
    res.writeHead(416,{
        "Content-Range":`bytes */*`
    }).send("Requires Range header");
    return;
    }
    try {
        const cursor = await bucket.find({ "_id": id });
        let size, type;
        await cursor.forEach(document => {
        size = document.length;
        type = document.metadata.mimeType;
        });
        let CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 *1024 ; // 1MB
        let start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
        const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, size-1);
        if(start>=size || start===end){
        res.writeHead(416,{
            "Content-Range":`bytes */${size}`
        })
        return res.end();
        }
        try {
        const downloadStream = await bucket.openDownloadStream(id, {
            start: start,
            end: end
        });
        const contentLength = end - start;
        const headers = {
            "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            "Content-Length": contentLength,
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        };
        res.writeHead(206, headers);
        downloadStream.pipe(res);
        } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        res.status(416).send();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        res.status(416).send();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved !!!
Problem was occurring when the range request were like close to end to file or when this code minm condition hit for size -1

```js
const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, **size-1**);
```

The problem here was the stream size:

```js
const downloadStream = await bucket.openDownloadStream(id, {
  start: start,
  **end: end**
});
```

Stream was never reaching its end

So if we configure the end to actual end this solve the problem

Final Code -

```js
route.get('/video/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const range = req.headers.range;
  try {
    const cursor = await bucket.find({ "_id": id }).toArray();
    const document = cursor[0];
    const size = document.length;
    const type = document.metadata.mimeType;
    if (range) {
      let CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
      var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
      var partialstart = parts[0];
      var partialend = parts[1];
      var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
      var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, size - 1);
      if (start >= size) {
        res.writeHead(416, {
          "Content-Range": `bytes */${size}`
        })
        return res.end();
      }
      try {

        const downloadStream = await bucket.openDownloadStream(id, {
          start: start,
          end: end == size - 1 ? size : end
        });
        const contentLength = end - start + 1;
        const headers = {
          "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
          "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
          "Content-Length": `${contentLength}`,
          "Content-Type": type,
        };
        res.writeHead(206, headers);
        console.info('Satisfied Range: ' + `${start}-${end}/${size}`);

        downloadStream.pipe(res);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        res.status(416).send();
      }
    } else {
      const downloadStream = await bucket.openDownloadStream(id);
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', size.toString());
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', type);
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(downloadStream);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    res.status(416).send();
  }
});
```